# How to populate select options dynamically from Model Collection

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I have a model as defined below

```
class Colors extends Backbone.Model
  name: -> [@get("name")]
  value: -> [@get("value")]
```

Collection as defined below

```
class @ColorsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Colors
```

Select tag as define below

```
%select{name: "colorslist" type: "hidden"  value: "" }
```

Upon an event, I want to dynamically populate the colorslist select options with data fetched from ColorsCollection.

I have been looking into select2 documentation but unable to find any relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will bind to the reset event and replace the html and start the select2 plugin.

I know the plugin has some internal ways of doing it  - but why deal with having to comb through the documentation.

```
class View extends Backbone.View

  initialize: -> 
   @collection = new ColorsCollection
   # Bind to reset event
   @listenTo @collection, "reset", @updateSelect
   @collection.fetch()

  updateSelect: (collection) ->
   # Use template engine (eg. Handlebars) to redraw the html
   @$el.find('#selection').html tmpl(@collection)
   # Start select2
   @$el.find('#selection > select').select2()
```